# Angular2, HTTP Request

Tags: angular

I have to make Login Page, but before I did it , I tried with simple HTTP get with JSON object. But the page does not load
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXCWd.png)

in some post I read that the arror `(index):18 Error: (SystemJS) XHR error (404 Not Found) loading` can be solve if I write in index.html this line

```html
<script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/http.dev.js"></script>
```

, but it does not load. I tried

```html
<script src="node_modules/@angular/bundles/http.dev.js"></script>
```

but nothing helped. In my imports I have @angular stead angular2

hier is my package.json

```js
{
  "name": "angular-quickstart",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "tsc && concurrently \"tsc -w\" \"lite-server\" ",
    "lite": "lite-server",
    "tsc": "tsc",
    "tsc:w": "tsc -w"
  },
  "licenses": [
    {
      "type": "MIT",
      "url": "https://github.com/angular/angular.io/blob/master/LICENSE"
    }
  ],
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "~2.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~2.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "~2.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~2.2.0",
   "@angular/http": "~2.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~2.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~2.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "~3.2.0",
    "@angular/upgrade": "~2.2.0",
    "angular-in-memory-web-api": "~0.1.15",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.8",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12",
    "systemjs": "0.19.39",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.25"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/core-js": "^0.9.34",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.45",
    "concurrently": "^3.0.0",
    "lite-server": "^2.2.2",
    "typescript": "^2.0.3"
  }
}
```

and my code 
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/d3b5f00ed5e9a5d3db603bf6eafb402f
and 
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/d6940887480a6501a539fa15f8de6b9f

thanks much for your help

Comment: You're gonna have to post some more code.

Comment: Do you have `@angular` under `node_modules`?

Comment: can you post your `packages.json`? Did you run `npm install`?

Comment: yes I have @angular under mode_modules.

Answer (score 0):

You need to import `HttpModule` into your module.

**app.module.ts**

```
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http'; // add this line

@NgModule({
    imports: [
       //....
       HttpModule //make sure you import `HttpModule` into `NgModule`
    ],
    // ...
)}
```